# Synology ipkg nano - line numbers are wrong, and sometimes appear on the wrong side of the file

Tags: nano, synology

##### update

I submitted [a bug report](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?61081) and the conclusion is that the nano version that's available through ipkg is 3 years outdated, and has been incorrectly modified or a dependency is broken.

Unfortunately the community-made package managers are either abandoned (ipkg) or incompatible (opkg). I suspect I'll run into similar problems if I keep trying to use the Synology for development so I'll try a different platform - but I'll leave this question up.

##### original

When I open any file in nano and line numbers are enabled, the line numbers are completely wrong, and appear on the wrong side!

This happens with any file. Here's one example:

[image: nano with wrong line numbers]

The actual file seems correct:

[image: actual file contents]

```bsh
➜  ngnix-proxy-manager cat -A docker-compose.yml
version: "3"$
services:$
  app:$
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'$
    restart: unless-stopped$
    ports:$
      # Public HTTP Port:$
      - '80:80'$
      # Public HTTPS Port:$
      - '443:443'$
      # Admin Web Port:$
      - '81:81'$
      # Add any other Stream port you want to expose$
      # - '21:21' # FTP$
    environment:$
      # These are the settings to access your db$
      DB_MYSQL_HOST: "db"$
      DB_MYSQL_PORT: 3306$
      DB_MYSQL_USER: "npm"$
      DB_MYSQL_PASSWORD: "npm"$
      DB_MYSQL_NAME: "npm"$
      # If you would rather use Sqlite uncomment this$
      # and remove all DB_MYSQL_* lines above$
      # DB_SQLITE_FILE: "/data/database.sqlite"$
      # Uncomment this if IPv6 is not enabled on your host$
      # DISABLE_IPV6: 'true'$
    volumes:$
      - ./data:/data$
      - ./letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt$
    depends_on:$
      - db$
  db:$
    image: 'jc21/mariadb-aria:latest'$
    restart: unless-stopped$
    environment:$
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'npm'$
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'npm'$
      MYSQL_USER: 'npm'$
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'npm'$
    volumes:$
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql$
➜  ngnix-proxy-manager od -c docker-compose.yml
0000000   v   e   r   s   i   o   n   :       "   3   "  \n   s   e   r
0000020   v   i   c   e   s   :  \n           a   p   p   :  \n
0000040           i   m   a   g   e   :       '   j   c   2   1   /   n
0000060   g   i   n   x   -   p   r   o   x   y   -   m   a   n   a   g
0000100   e   r   :   l   a   t   e   s   t   '  \n                   r
0000120   e   s   t   a   r   t   :       u   n   l   e   s   s   -   s
0000140   t   o   p   p   e   d  \n                   p   o   r   t   s
0000160   :  \n                           #       P   u   b   l   i   c
0000200       H   T   T   P       P   o   r   t   :  \n
0000220           -       '   8   0   :   8   0   '  \n
0000240           #       P   u   b   l   i   c       H   T   T   P   S
0000260       P   o   r   t   :  \n                           -       '
0000300   4   4   3   :   4   4   3   '  \n                           #
0000320       A   d   m   i   n       W   e   b       P   o   r   t   :
0000340  \n                           -       '   8   1   :   8   1   '
0000360  \n                           #       A   d   d       a   n   y
0000400       o   t   h   e   r       S   t   r   e   a   m       p   o
0000420   r   t       y   o   u       w   a   n   t       t   o       e
0000440   x   p   o   s   e  \n                           #       -
0000460   '   2   1   :   2   1   '       #       F   T   P  \n
0000500           e   n   v   i   r   o   n   m   e   n   t   :  \n
0000520                       #       T   h   e   s   e       a   r   e
0000540       t   h   e       s   e   t   t   i   n   g   s       t   o
0000560       a   c   c   e   s   s       y   o   u   r       d   b  \n
0000600                           D   B   _   M   Y   S   Q   L   _   H
0000620   O   S   T   :       "   d   b   "  \n
0000640   D   B   _   M   Y   S   Q   L   _   P   O   R   T   :       3
0000660   3   0   6  \n                           D   B   _   M   Y   S
0000700   Q   L   _   U   S   E   R   :       "   n   p   m   "  \n
0000720                       D   B   _   M   Y   S   Q   L   _   P   A
0000740   S   S   W   O   R   D   :       "   n   p   m   "  \n
0000760                   D   B   _   M   Y   S   Q   L   _   N   A   M
0001000   E   :       "   n   p   m   "  \n                           #
0001020       I   f       y   o   u       w   o   u   l   d       r   a
0001040   t   h   e   r       u   s   e       S   q   l   i   t   e
0001060   u   n   c   o   m   m   e   n   t       t   h   i   s  \n
0001100                       #       a   n   d       r   e   m   o   v
0001120   e       a   l   l       D   B   _   M   Y   S   Q   L   _   *
0001140       l   i   n   e   s       a   b   o   v   e  \n
0001160               #       D   B   _   S   Q   L   I   T   E   _   F
0001200   I   L   E   :       "   /   d   a   t   a   /   d   a   t   a
0001220   b   a   s   e   .   s   q   l   i   t   e   "  \n
0001240               #       U   n   c   o   m   m   e   n   t       t
0001260   h   i   s       i   f       I   P   v   6       i   s       n
0001300   o   t       e   n   a   b   l   e   d       o   n       y   o
0001320   u   r       h   o   s   t  \n                           #
0001340   D   I   S   A   B   L   E   _   I   P   V   6   :       '   t
0001360   r   u   e   '  \n                   v   o   l   u   m   e   s
0001400   :  \n                           -       .   /   d   a   t   a
0001420   :   /   d   a   t   a  \n                           -       .
0001440   /   l   e   t   s   e   n   c   r   y   p   t   :   /   e   t
0001460   c   /   l   e   t   s   e   n   c   r   y   p   t  \n
0001500           d   e   p   e   n   d   s   _   o   n   :  \n
0001520                   -       d   b  \n           d   b   :  \n
0001540               i   m   a   g   e   :       '   j   c   2   1   /
0001560   m   a   r   i   a   d   b   -   a   r   i   a   :   l   a   t
0001600   e   s   t   '  \n                   r   e   s   t   a   r   t
0001620   :       u   n   l   e   s   s   -   s   t   o   p   p   e   d
0001640  \n                   e   n   v   i   r   o   n   m   e   n   t
0001660   :  \n                           M   Y   S   Q   L   _   R   O
0001700   O   T   _   P   A   S   S   W   O   R   D   :       '   n   p
0001720   m   '  \n                           M   Y   S   Q   L   _   D
0001740   A   T   A   B   A   S   E   :       '   n   p   m   '  \n
0001760                       M   Y   S   Q   L   _   U   S   E   R   :
0002000       '   n   p   m   '  \n                           M   Y   S
0002020   Q   L   _   P   A   S   S   W   O   R   D   :       '   n   p
0002040   m   '  \n                   v   o   l   u   m   e   s   :  \n
0002060                           -       .   /   d   a   t   a   /   m
0002100   y   s   q   l   :   /   v   a   r   /   l   i   b   /   m   y
0002120   s   q   l  \n
0002124
```

Versions:

- Synology DSM `6.2.4-25556`
- `GNU nano, version 3.1`

I've tried different combinations of shells and clients - the same problem occurs:

- GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
- `zsh 5.2 (x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu)`
- ohmyzsh - [latest master](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/commit/6d5b8484ce7198161d5f617c3db9fd7d3833d48c)
- OS X Terminal
- Windows Terminal `1.9.1942.0`, with profile Powershell `7.1.3`

I've tried reinstalling `sudo /opt/bin/ipkg install nano --force-reinstall`

nano correctly reads the nanorc file

```
> more $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nano/nanorc
set linenumbers
```

Once I even got a crash:

```
> nano docker-compose.yml.save
Sorry! Nano crashed!  Code: 11.  Please report a bug.
```

The line number changes when I edit the content of a line: https://gfycat.com/unripeoblongafricanhornbill

1. `211` - [image: line-number-changes-0]
2. `225` - [image: line-number-changes-1]
3. `239` - [image: line-number-changes-2]

When line numbers are disabled, nano works correctly. Here I've commented out the setting, and re-opened nanorc:

[image: no-line-numbers-and-correct]

#### Updated to DSM 7

I updated my Synology to DSM 7 and tried using nano again. Again, without `set linenumbers`, the output is garbled. Also, I get some nice error messages:

`Badness: tried to display a line on row -1851878901 -- please report a bug`

[image]

The row number changes a few times as the file is loaded, before I get this error:

`Further warnings were suppressed`

[image]

Comment: Does that happen with every file or just that one? If you look at the file with `cat -A docker-compose.yaml`, or even `od -c docker-compose.yaml`, is there anything odd in there, like stray escape codes? In any case, that does sound a bit like something that would be a bug in nano, and you might get better answers from its developers.

Comment: It happens with all files. Thanks for the commands, I've put the output in the question. I should also clarify that I'm using Windows Terminal / Powershell to ssh in. Thinking about it now I realise that it is a bit ridiculous that I'm using Terminal+Powershell+ssh+omz+zsh and 2 different OSes - something in this chain could be going wrong?

Comment: Update: I've ssh'd in with a Macbook and the exact same problem occurs, down to the same problem with the line numbers. It's something local to the Synology environment.

Comment: Ok, yeah, the file seems normal. I don't know anything about Synology, so I can't say anything about that. Just reminds me of an issue with GNU screen, if you fumble line wrapping off. Unclean terminal emulation can do strange stuff.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! I rolled back your recent edit adding an answer to the question in the text of the question. If you have a solution then consider adding that solution as a separate answer and accept it later. Accepting an answer will mark the question as resolved. Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @Kusalananda Hi, you rolled back an update, not an answer. There is no solution or conclusion as the issue is under investigation.

Answer (score 0):

[Copied from the question so that it's an answer. This is from the original poster]

I submitted [a bug report](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?61081) and the conclusion is that the nano version that's available through ipkg is 3 years outdated, and has been incorrectly modified or a dependency is broken.

Unfortunately the community-made package managers are either abandoned (ipkg) or incompatible (opkg). I suspect I'll run into similar problems if I keep trying to use the Synology for development so I'll try a different platform - but I'll leave this question up.

Comment: This is an update, not an answer, as the issue is not resolved or identified and has no workaround.

Comment: @aSemy an answer explaining there is no solution is a valid answer

Comment: My update does not specify there is no solution. It indicates potential causes and impediments.

Comment: @aSemy It seems to me that this text _resolves_ the issue for now. It may not be a good resolution, but it's currently the best one. Whenever the bug report is acted upon (or not), the answer could be updated.

Comment: "Here is a potential cause and also it is difficult to resolve" is not a resolution. I would be irritated if I had this problem, came to a site for a solution, and there is no solution.

Comment: @aSemy Well, I'd also be irritated if a problem did not have a solution, but sometimes you can't resolve issues in a way that the original poster may ideally want, and then an answer saying "it's a known issue" is the best there's ever going to be.

Comment: `The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”` > the "answer" you are pushing does not contain any useful information. It contains a potential cause and impediments, but no path forward.

Comment: @aSemy That's the nature of "known issues", unless you're the developer working to fix it, obviously.

Comment: @Kusalananda The "answer" doesn't even identify *where* the issue is occurring, let alone that is is a 'known' issue. It is information that is useful for investigation, not resolution, and as such is not an answer.

Comment: @roaima I am unhappy that you have copy and and pasted my text without discussing it with me first, and I would appreciate it if you removed it.